# ClassCastException in customComponentcontroller model

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have created my custom ABC component extending the SimpleCMSComponentModel.
It is giving class cast exception in ABCComponentController - > fillModel

java.lang.ClassCastException: de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.components.SimpleCMSComponentModel cannot be cast to ABCComponentController

Any suggestion will be helpfull

Comment: Can you please show is the code and the stacktrace? But I can remeber that something with "instance of" will handle this problem.

Comment: restart has solved the problem. not sure whatz the issue

Comment: You may find your answer here : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/create-a-custom-cms-component-in-hybris/

Answer (score 1):

You must be forgot to change your custom model from SimpleCMSComponentModel  to ABCComponentModel.

This should be like this

```
@Controller("ABCComponentController")
@Scope("tenant")
@RequestMapping(value = ControllerConstants.Actions.Cms.ABCComponentController)
public class ABCComponentController extends AbstractCMSComponentController<ABCComponentModel>
{
    /**
    * Fill Model
    */
    @Override
    protected void fillModel(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model, final ABCComponentModel component)
    {
      //
    }

}
```

where

`ControllerConstants.Actions.Cms.ABCComponentController = "/view/ABCComponentController";` or your custom path..